# How to access through terminal to a ntfs partition mounted?

Tags: mount, partition, automounting

Using Debian 7, I can access (and mount, indeed) to a ntfs partition of my hard drive.I do this by clicking on the 446 GB Filesystem shorcut in the *"Files"* applicacion which comes with Debian.

How can I access to such mounted partition from terminal? And how can I make this partition to be always loaded automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've mounted the disk on your desktop use the `mount` command to get hold the partition and disk the NTFS filesystem is. It will one that the line looks a bit like:

```
 /dev/sdb1 on /some/mount/point type ntfs
```

`/dev/sdb1` could be any number of disks `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` etc and any one of the partitions on that disk `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc2`, `/dev/sdb3` etc. `/some/mount/point` will be where debian `automounted` that partition. I suggest for the purpose of mounting it "automatically", you pick a different mount point. `mkdir /ntfsdisk` or similar for a mount point, the location and name of this is your choice. As well as this you can mount the disk to have a specific ownership (so for example your non-root user can get access to files). In which case use the `id` command and make note of your uid (for example it may be 1000). If you do want access for that user, you will need to set filw ownership on the mount point `chown username /ntfsdisk` where username is the username of the user you want to give access to.

Once you've identified the ntfs disk and decided on a place to mount it (and made the directory) you will need to add an entry to your /etc/fstab with an editor. You will have to edit `/etc/fstab` as a root user or via the sudo command. The entry should look similar
to:

```
 /dev/sdb1   /ntfsdisk  ntfs   defaults,user,uid=1000   0 2
```

That should be enough for it to be auto mounted on your next boot. You can get an idea of what that line in the fstab means by looking at the man page for it `man fstab`. I would test the mount point once you added it to the fstab by umounting the mount point automounted by your window manager. You can do that either via your window manager, or via the `umount` command. You should then be able to `mount /ntfsdisk`.

Comment: Is is possible to add any *code line* so it deletes any hibernation file on mounting as it's actually a Windows partition?

Comment: And by the way, pretty well answered, Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are falling across this problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

to mount it automatically, you will need to make an entry in fstab. just google it and that will give you plenty of results. As a side effect you will pick up a lot of cool stuff that you might like (looking at ur intrest in the command line) the term you are looking for for the command line mount will be "mount options for ntfs"